# Where is JRE folder in Java 9?

Tags: java, java-9

Where is JRE folder in Java 9? I have seen in some site that JRE is present in a separate distribution folder. But where it is located?

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: It is, and always has been, a separate folder in a *JDK* installation. If you just install the JRE, it isn't.

Comment: Next to JavaX version you had had installed before.

Comment: @EJP no, this is actually something pretty significantly different with JDK 9.  There is no JRE folder at all and there is no longer a distinction between a JRE or JDK.  This is a perfectly valid question IMO

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The JDK and JRE run-time images have been restructured in JDK 9. The JDK run-time image no longer includes a "jre" sub-directory.

A summary of the restructuring is documented in the JDK 9 release notes ([Modular Run-Time Images note](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-relnote-issues-3704069.html#JDK-8049367)).

[JEP 220](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220) documents the motivations and all the details of the new layout.

The changes have been in JDK 9 early access builds since late 2014 to give tools and libraries that depend on the legacy structure time to adjust - hopefully the tools that that you use have already been updated.

Comment: When I downloaded for Windows, I got a separate JRE directory (didn't get it for Linux, which I'm more comfortable with). Can I delete the separate JRE directory and just put the JDK on Windows's PATH?

Comment: This is a developer forum, so people don't just use tools, they also make tools. So we don't expect our own tools to fix themselves.