# How to find the directory location of JRE?

Tags: java

This might sound very dumb but I am not being able to locate my JRE folder. I had installed JDK 11. My `C:\Program Files\Java` folder contains only `jdk-11.0.1` folder. It does not contain a JRE folder. I need the location of my JRE folder for setting up a Tomcat server. How can I find the location of my JRE?

Comment: did you check inside `jdk-11.0.1` ?

Comment: As of Java 11 they jdk does not contain a separate jre any more as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52586617/8362098)

Comment: As christoph Bohme told , there is no JRE folder from JAVA 9 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388117/where-is-jre-folder-in-java-9/46388190. Why you need JRE Folder for tomcat, instead of you can use JAVA_HOME. when you look the catalina.bat or catalina.sh for the description of JRE_HOME says that  **JRE_HOME - Must point at your Java Runtime installation. Defaults to JAVA_HOME if empty. If JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME are both set, JRE_HOME is used.**