# How to configure GraalVm 20.1.0 to run with sbt plugin for Intellji

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, graalvm

with GraalVM Version 20.X.X I encounter problems configure Intellijs sbt plugin to run with latest graal package. When running my applications it fails the process with Error Message `Could not found valid JRE in path $HOME/graal-20.1.0/`.

Previous versions of GraalVM contained a separate jre/ folder which worked great.

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: The `jre` folder is present in JDK 8-based GraalVMs. The ones without `jre` are based on JDK 11. Both options are available for GraalVM 20.1.0.

Comment: Ah okay why is it though?

Comment: The `jre` folder was removed in JDK 9. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46388190/1885085).